# Logic gates and osquarepole in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I have this little problem, I would like to resolve, how can I put some squared terminal with the usual syntax  `to [short, -s]` or  `to [short, s-]`, without having to specify both stile, `-s` and `s-`in the beginning by the `ctikzset{}` option.
The diamond shape works, but the squared terminal was left with the bare short.

When the `s` option is commentend
[image]

When I use the option
[image]

In both case I compiled with XeLaTeX with TexStudio in W10.

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale = 0.8, transform shape]
        \ctikzset{
            logic ports=ieee,
            logic ports/scale=0.8,
            component text=left,    
            -s/.style = {bipole nodes={none}{osquarepole, }},       %% square --
            s-/.style = {bipole nodes={osquarepole,}{none }},       %% -- square
        }

        }       
        %% NOR_3_1 in 2 ports gates
        \filldraw [blue , %very thick,
        line width =0.75pt ,
        dashed , fill = blue!8]
        (-4.25,5) -| (1.95,1.5) -| cycle;
        \node [rounded corners, black, draw, fill = blue!8] at (.95 ,1.88)
        { \textcolor{blue}{\small { LG2 }}};
        %%  dividing the NOR3
        \draw 
            (-1,4) node[not port,](not2){\scriptsize lg2} (not2.out) -- ($(not2.out)+(0.3,0)$) coordinate(notAB) 
            (notAB)node[above right]{\scriptsize $\overline{\overline{A + B}}=A+B$}
            (-3,4) node[nor port](norAB){\scriptsize lg3} (norAB.out) -- (not2.in 1)
            (-4.5,4.5) node[left]{\footnotesize A} to [short, s-] (-4,4.5) |- (norAB.in 1)
            (-4.5,3.5) node[left]{\footnotesize B} to [short, s-] (-4,3.5) |- (norAB.in 2)
            (norAB.out)node[above, xshift=3mm]{\scriptsize$\overline{\mbox{A + B}}$}
        ;
        \draw 
            (1,3) node[nor port,](exNor3){\scriptsize lg1} 
            (notAB) |- (exNor3.in 1)
            (-4.5,2.5) node[left]{\footnotesize C} to [short, s-] (-0,2.5) |- (exNor3.in 2)
        ;
        \draw (1,0) node[nor port, anchor=center](Nor2){\scriptsize LG1};
        \draw 
            (-4.5,-0.5) node[left]{\footnotesize E} to [short, s-] (0,-0.5) |- (Nor2.in 2)
            (-4.5,0.5)node[left]{\footnotesize D} to [short, s-] (0,0.5) |- (Nor2.in 1)
        ;
        \draw           
            (exNor3.out) -- ($(exNor3.out) + (0.5,0)$) coordinate(ABC)  node[right=1mm]{\scriptsize$\overline{\mbox{A + B + C}}$}
            (Nor2.out) -- ($(Nor2.out) + (0.5,0)$) coordinate(DE)   node[right=2mm]{\scriptsize$\overline{\mbox{D+E}}$} 
        ;
        \draw 
            (4,1.5) node[nand port] (Nand2){\scriptsize LG3}
            (DE) |- (Nand2.in 2)
            (ABC) |- (Nand2.in 1)
            (Nand2.out) -- ($(Nand2.out) + (0.5,0)$) coordinate(notF) node[above left]{\scriptsize$\overline{\mbox{F}}$}
        ;
        \draw 
            (6,1.5) node [not port](not1){\scriptsize LG4}
            (Nand2.out) -- (not1.in 1)
            (not1.out) to [short, -s] ($(not1.out)+ (0.5,0)$) node[right]{\footnotesize F}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\caption{pic caption here}
\label{fig:Fco_2}
\end{figure}
```

PS. I copied post submit, and I used the one with the circle in my report, my bad.

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question. Can you please a) prepare a *minimum* example, with just one element; b) add a figure/diagram/ sketch showing what you need. Thanks!

Comment: More in detail, you are not using any `s-` or diamond shapes in your example. As it is, this question is impossible to answer; I'll vote for closing, please edit it and I'll remove the vote.

Comment: @Rmano I was running late for my sbmission and changed to a more classic looking diagram,. As stated in the beginning, it's a really small problem, just a little annoying, I copiet from an example in the manual, but it works only with the option declared explicitly beforehand.

Comment: Yes, `s-` and `-s` and `s-s` are not defined by default, you have to add them. Best option is to use a personal style file, or you can just stick them in your preamble and they'll be valid in all of your file.

Comment: @Rmano I'm still working on my personal style file, and something is telling me it will never be finished ;) There will alway be something new needing to be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as you have discovered, the `-s` connection types are not defined by default. You can see from the manual in chapter 6.1, "Nodes (also called poles)" that the predefined ones are (most of) the combinations of `o`, `*`, `d`, and `.`. So you have to add it yourself when you want them.

You can just copy them to the preamble, making them available in all of your file, or you can stick them to a style file (see chapter 3.3.5,  "Style files: how to write them").

The simpler option is to have them in your preamble:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{
    -s/.style = {bipole nodes={none}{osquarepole}},
    s-/.style = {bipole nodes={osquarepole}{none}},
    s-s/.style = {bipole nodes={osquarepole}{osquarepoles}},
    % add the combinations you need, for example
    s-*/.style = {bipole nodes={osquarepole}{circ}},
    % you can see in the file pgfcircpath.tex the predefined ones
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,1) to[short, s-] ++(2,0);
    \draw (0,0) to[R, s-*] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]